# Why can't I delete this file from my Xcode project?

Tags: xcode, delete-file

Being new to Xcode, I foolishly added "wrong_answer.mp3" via "add files to.." to my project and in the wrong place, but I cannot remove this reference from my project. I deleted the underlying file from the file system, but I cannot find in Xcode where I can remove this reference... Can someone advise how to remove this reference from my project ?

[image]

UPDATE: Yes, I have tried delete/backspace and edit menu "Delete".

Comment: @clemens ok.. BTW I already tried delete/backspace, as well as right-click and also from the edit menu for "delete" but it's also disabled.

Comment: I upvoted because of the rage meme :-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Some options

1. Restart Xcode
2. Clean project, Product—>Clean
3. Put the file back and delete it from Xcode

Comment: I like working with Xcode but yes, sometimes it can misbehave